# SQLite-net: Duplicate column name when creating table

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm trying to create a table in my local SQLite database made with the library found at https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

I've managed to set up the database, but when I add a table by calling...

```
database.CreateTable<Session>();
```

...I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: NUnit.Framework.Internal.NUnitException: Rethrown ---> SQLite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: PersonNumber
```

Here's the class that I'm trying to store:

```
public class Session
{
    public Session()
    {

    }

    public Session(string personNumber, Order order, Orderlist orderlist)
    {
        PersonNumber = personNumber;
        Order = order;
        SerializedOrder = _orderSerializer.Serialize(Order);
        Orderlist = orderlist;
        SerializedOrderlist = _orderlistSerializer.Serialize(Orderlist);
    }

    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string PersonNumber { get; set; }

    public string SerializedOrder { get; set; }

    public string SerializedOrderlist { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public Order Order
    {
        get
        {
            if (Order == null) Order = _orderSerializer.Deserialize(SerializedOrder);
            return Order;
        }
        private set { Order = value; }
    }

    [Ignore]
    public Orderlist Orderlist
    {
        get
        {
            if (Orderlist == null) Orderlist = _orderlistSerializer.Deserialize(SerializedOrderlist);
            return Orderlist;
        }
        private set { Orderlist = value; }
    }

    private static XmlStringSerializer<Order> _orderSerializer = new XmlStringSerializer<Order>();
    private static XmlStringSerializer<Orderlist> _orderlistSerializer = new XmlStringSerializer<Orderlist>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Linking** :

> SDK and User Assemblies

**Skip Linking** :

> SQLite-net;SQLitePCL.raw